# Как получить начало и конец текущего дня в t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть длинный SQL-запрос для базы 1С, хочу в запрос добавить конструкцию, которая помогла бы вытащить начало текущего дня и конец дня.
Т.е. если сегодня, скажем, 2022-01-01, хочу получить:

2022-01-01 00:00:00
2022-01-01 23:59:59

Написал конструкцию:

1. dateadd(year,2000,dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0))
2. dateadd(year,2000,dateadd(second,-1,dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0,
   getdate())+1, 0)))

Отрабатывает запрос некорректно. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Есть такая штука — часовые пояса называется.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7fe487db74b97aab8e229ab58a2e969d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select cast(floor(cast( GETDATE() as float)) as datetime) valid_from,

DATEADD(SECOND, -1, cast(floor(cast( GETDATE() as float)) + 1 as datetime))